# How to nest a Rails scriptlets within each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations

I have got a few models that are different types of user account - i.e. a User model, an Admin model, a Guest model.

I'm trying to create a forum as part of an application I am making. When a post is created, the user_type attribute is set to the type of user that created the post. What I want to do seems to be something pretty simple, but I can't seem to work it out. Basically, I want to get the username of the person that created the post. I can't just use something like post.user.username, as I have a few different models, and I don't want to have to do something ugly with if statements, so is there a better way around? This might show what I'm trying to achieve (although this doesn't work):

```
created by:<%= post.#{user_type}.username %>
```

which would then output to the relevant code:

```
post.user.username
or post.admin.username
or post.guest.username
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best course of action

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def username
    [user,admin,guest].find(&:present?).try(:username)
  end
end
```

You can stick this in your model, or even better, a [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Now you can just do this in your view:

```
created by:<%= post.username %>
```

`find` retrieves the first thing that responds to `present?`. In other words, it finds the first thing that is not nil. Then, we try to call `username` on whatever that method returns. If there is no `user`, `admin`, or `guest` for this post, the method will return `nil`.

Comment: Can't test it at present, but this looks like just what I was after, thanks. Will accept when tested.